# My javascript bookmarklet doesn't work

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmark of javascript code, but nothing happens when I click on it. It works with an input button though.

Here's the javascript code:

```
javascript:(function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {if (typeof ul == "string")    ul = document.getElementsByTagName("mbp:frameset")[0];    var lis = ul.querySelectorAll("[name='french']");  var vals = [];  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);  vals.sort();  if (sortDescending)    vals.reverse();  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];}window.addEventListener("load", function() {  var desc = false;  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {sortUnorderedList("list", desc);    desc = !desc;    return false;}))();
```

Here's the html code:

```
    <mbp:frameset>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion B</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition B</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion A</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition A</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion C</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition C</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
</mbp:frameset>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong in my code?

Comment: 1. What are you trying to make happen? 2. How exactly are making it work with an input button?